# QISDK API6 GoTo

Tags: pepper

Pepper got a new API update recently and we wanted to try out new  **navigation function, exactly... GoTo**.

New QISDK plugin update in Android Studio + API 6 and JDK1.8 installed as mentioned in the requirements and new parameters for GoTo ( MaxSpeed, PathPlanning etc. ) are shown and usable, bet when we launch our activity and it builds the code it **throws exception**

```
W/System.err: Uncaught exception on Future: Could not find suitable method 'makeGoTo' in the given object for parameter types: (com.aldebaran.qi.AnyObject, com.aldebaran.qi.AnyObject, com.aldebaran.qi.Tuple). Candidates are: 'makeGoTo::(oo)'.
W/System.err: com.aldebaran.qi.QiException: Could not find suitable method 'makeGoTo' in the given object for parameter types: (com.aldebaran.qi.AnyObject, com.aldebaran.qi.AnyObject, com.aldebaran.qi.Tuple). Candidates are: 'makeGoTo::(oo)'.
```

when we try - > try - catch block says that this block even cannot throw QiException.

*Same thing for new classes like HumanApproach as well...*

What could be possible problem? Please help!

Comment: I notived Pepper could be updated today to 2.9.4 on the tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API 6 is only available from Naoqi 2.9.4 which is going to be release this week.